# How to use query caching in yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, caching, activerecord, yii2

I am quoting the guide:

``Query caching is a special caching feature built on top of data caching. It is provided to cache the result of database queries.

Query caching requires a DB connection and a valid cache application component. The basic usage of query caching is as follows, assuming $db is a yii\db\Connection instance:

```
$result = $db->cache(function ($db) {

    // the result of the SQL query will be served from the cache
    // if query caching is enabled and the query result is found in the cache
    return $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=1')->queryOne();

});
```

``

I do not think that I will manually create db connection in AR classes. So how to do this in my AR models ?

I have asked [the same question](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61030-query-cashing-in-activerecord/) on yii2 forum but I got no answer. It seems that people do not know how to do query caching in Active Record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii 2 now requires closures to wrap the query. AR does a query eventually so you can put that in the closure. In an AR class, get the db and wrap the query you want to use. The closure has a signature *function($db)* and you usually need to access more variables, so add *use($variable)* to make variables visible within the closure.

```
    $db = self::getDb();
    $object = $db->cache(function ($db) use($id) {
        return self::findOne($id);
    });
```

If you write to the db, the cache above won't know about it until the cache duration expires. So dependency should be added to the cache function to tell it when to invalidate the cache. Dependency gets complicated fast...
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-dependency.html

Comment: Did you check this method? It's not working, it's always getting data from mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854882/yii2-activerecord-cache

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help: [yii2 issues on github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1917)

> qiangxue commented on 11 Jan 2014
>
> In 2.0, you need to use the following code:

```
$db->beginCache();
// your db query code here...
$db->endCache();
```

Comment: Nope. I need a way to cache query in my AR model.