# Yii2 ActiveRecord cache

Tags: caching, activerecord, yii, yii2

How to use ActiveRecotd cache for Yii 2? I did't find any examples in official docs. In Google I found 2 examples, first is:

```
$db = self::getDb();
$object = $db->cache(function ($db) use($id) {
    return self::findOne($id);
});
```

But it doesn't work for `Model`, I tested with updated framework. Other example is:

```
$data = \Yii::$app->cache->get('some_var_' . $id);
if ($data === false)
{
    $data = self::findOne($id);
    \Yii::$app->cache->set('some_var_' . $id, $data, 60);
}
```

It's working fine, but it's not ActiveRecord caching it's data caching, So we haven't got ActiveRecord caching in Yii 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Use cache like that:

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;// or Category::getDb()
$result = $db->cache(function ($db) use ($id) {
    return Category::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
}, CACHE_TIMEOUT);
```

2) If you may use query dependency, use like that:

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;// or Category::getDb()
$dep = new DbDependency();
$dep->sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM category';
$result = $db->cache(function ($db) use ($id) {
    return Category::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
}, CACHE_TIMEOUT, $dep);
```

Answer (score 3):

I too am having trouble with this. Here's my workaround for the time being for a hasOne() relationship.

```
public function getGroup()
{
    if(isset(static::$_getGroup[$this->id])) {
        return static::$_getGroup[$this->id];
    }
    $Group = $this->hasOne(BillChargesGroup::className(), ['id' => 'group_id'])->one();
    static::$_getGroup[$this->id] = $Group;
    return $Group;
}
```

I only want to cache data for the current request, so this works. However because I'm using `->one();` it does not return the ActiveQuery object if we call `$model->getGroup()` (which I found is good for extending queries)

Unfortunately if I do return the ActiveQuery object, Yii2 does some "magic" on it and always does a SELECT * which I can't control.

Comment: In Yii AR you could use: $model->getGroup() to get ActiveQuery or $model->group to get BillChangesGroup object (Yii2 magic ->group == getGroup()->one() in your example). In your solution you miss this.

Comment: Thank for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.0.14 you can use the following shortcuts:

```
(new Query())->cache(7200)->all();
// and
User::find()->cache(7200)->all();
```

Source: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data