# How to add values to cache

Tags: php, caching, yii2

I am using file cache in yii2 framework.
**My question is**
Is it possible to add some extra value to cache without refresh the cacheFile.Suppose i create cache file for my products now on each entry i update cache file. I want to add just the new product to cache.
How can i do that thanks in advance
**This is my Code**

```
public static function updateCache(){
    $product_grid = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("CALL get_products()")->queryAll();
    Yii::$app->cache->set('product_grid', $product_grid);
}
```

I write store procedure for getting all products,now when i add new product each time i am calling the updateCache function which regenerate the products and add it to cache due to which application speed may be effected.
This is the code for `addingProduct` and `updateCache`:

```
public function actionCreate($id = NULL) {
    $model = new PrProducts();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->save(false);
        self::updateCache();
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer the official documentation [Query Caching and Cache Dependencies](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-dependencies)

Comment: Also refer [Yii2 ActiveRecord cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854882/yii2-activerecord-cache). may be helpfull

Answer (score 2):

Native Yii2 cache components doesn't allow **to update** existing cache items **partially**. 
But you can do this manually:

```
public static function addToCache($modelProduct) {

    $productGrid                    = Yii::$app->cache->get('productGrid');
    $productGrid[$modelProduct->id] = $modelProduct->attributes;

    Yii::$app->cache->set('productGrid', $productGrid);
}
```

But I recommend other way: you can store each product record as separate cache item.
Firstly you can add multiple items:

```
public static function refreshProductCache() {

    // Retrieve the all products
    $products = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("CALL get_products()")->queryAll();

    // Prepare for storing to cache
    $productsToCache = [];
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productId                                = $product['id'];
        $productsToCache['product_' . $productId] = $product;
    }

    // Store to cache (existing values will be replaced)
    Yii::$app->cache->multiSet($productsToCache);
}
```

Secondly you can update cache when you **read** data. For instance:

```
public function actionView($id) {

    $model = Yii::$app->cache->getOrSet('product_'.$id, function() use ($id) {
        return PrProducts::find()
            ->andWhere(['id' => $id])
            ->one();
    });

    return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

This code creates cache only one time for each `$id` that not yet present in the cache.

Thirdly you can add individual products to cache right **after create/update**. For instance:

```
public static function addToCache(PrProducts $modelProduct) {
    $productId = $modelProduct->id;

    Yii::$app->cache->set('product_' . $productId, $modelProduct);
}
```

I think this approach more flexible. Of course, it may be less efficient than you way. It very depends from code that reads your cache.

Comment: your code cached only the $id record which is not relevant to my question...... i want to add the new record to the cache which have all the product data it is possible or not.....???

Comment: @Dani I extended my answer.

Comment: @IStrabger thanks for your suggestion.... but what i want to access all the products from cache instead of db??? Your code still created acache for an individual product

Comment: @Dani Yes, this code stores cache items for individual product, but you can update cache using `refreshProductCache()` and `addToCache()`. In this case all data will be retrieved from cache storage instead DB (as you want).

Comment: hmm thats cool thanks for your help @IStranger let me try it thanks alot