# Yii2 Facebook auth success once after PHP restarts, fails afterwards

Tags: php, facebook, nginx, yii2, fpm

I'm using facebook login on my Yii2 app by following this tutorial: https://mushtaqtahir.com/blog/2/facebook-authentication-using-yii2-authclient

It works without problems for months, but suddenly a problem occured. When I try to login, it give error 502 after succesfully logged in on Facebook and return to the app. I try to restart PHP FPM on the server. It works just once after PHP restarted, but continue to fail afterwards.

I check nginx error log and found this:

```
2017/05/31 05:49:30 [error] 7368#7368: *151 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) 
while reading response header from upstream, client: 103.47.104.104, server: my.app, request: 
"GET /site/auth?authclient=facebook&code=AQA5h_.....gIdRKg&state=6a424...7efc 
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "my.app"
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: may be this discussion can help  you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616191/nginx-php-fpm-502-bad-gateway?rq=1

Comment: Wow, thank you, I disabled opcache and it worked. However, I need cache in my app. Any other workaround?

Comment: Yii2 ActiveRecord cache, Go through this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854882/yii2-activerecord-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Thanks to @vijay-nathji who pointed in the right direction!

This is actually a bug in PHP 7 ([Bug #73310 PECL OAuth segfaults when OPcache is enabled in PHP 7](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73310)). This problem should be fixed in PHP 7.1.3, but I need a quick solution.

So what I did is disabled OPC only on the specific function that handle the Facebook login. I add on the `frontend/config/main.php` :

```
'on beforeRequest' => function(){
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'auth') !== false){
        ini_set('opcache.enable', false);
    }
},
```

Comment: Glad to hear from you that my direction helps you. Enjoy Coding :)